# How can I find an element ID when I only know the text inside the element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with id="main-form" and inside that there's a class="block-footer"

Inside that an element:

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

How can I use jQuery to find this button without my adding an Id to the element? The button always has the text of Submit.

Is it worth using the id="main-form" as a starting point in my selection to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all the `<button>` elements, then filter them based on their `innerHTML`:

```
$('button').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML == 'Submit';
});
```

If needed you can be more explicit by only selecting button elements with `type="button"`, although this is slightly less efficient:

```
$('button[type="button"]').filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML == 'Submit';
});
```

As for your comment:

> Can I make it more efficient as I know that button is inside a div with a class I know and also inside my form with known ID?

Sure you can.

```
var $container = $('.element-that-contains-the-button');
$('button', $container).filter(function() {
  return this.innerHTML == 'Submit';
});
```

You could also use `$container.find()`, which has the exact same effect.

Comment: Can I make it more efficient as I know that button is inside a div with a class I know and also inside my form with known ID?

Answer (score 1):

This will select all the buttons containing the text "Submit".

```
$('button:contains("Submit")')...
```

Or if you know more about the element it can be found inside:

```
$('.block-footer button:contains("Submit")')...
```

Comment: That would match `<button>Not the Submit you’re looking for</button>` as well.

Comment: But can I make it a bit more efficient as I know that button is inside a div with a class I know and also inside my form with known ID?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('#main-form button:contains("submit")')` will give you buttons of type submit inside mainform having submit text.

Comment: My button doesn't have a type of submit :-(

Comment: Edited and removed type= submit

Comment: it will now select buttons inside mainform having text submit

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery [Contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

```
var yourButton = $('button:Contains("Submit")');
```

Comment: That would match `<button>Not the Submit you’re looking for</button>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the :contains selector.

This would work for your question:

```
$(":contains('Submit')").Action()
```

Comment: That would match `<button>Not the Submit you’re looking for</button>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage this code

jQuery('document').ready(function()
{
   jQuery('form').find('button').addClass('hi')
});

Answer (score 0):

Since you already knew the form ID, you just have to loop each button element with and check if it contains Submit text.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#main-form button").each(function(e){
             var btnCaption = $(this).text();
            if(btnCaption == 'Submit'){
                //do something
                alert('hey, i am the submit button');
            }
        });

    });
```

I've included a working example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NwTK5/1/)